# How to get country, state, city name in most optimized way from different collections

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I have an employee collection with current address field as follows:

```
{
  currentAddr:{
    line1:'abc',
    line2:'def',
    country: countryId,
    state: stateId,
    city: cityId,
  }
}
```

countryId, stateId, cityId is represented by _id in country, state, city collections respectively.
What will be the optimized pipeline for resolving countryId,stateId,cityId to their corresponding names from their respective tables?

Answer (score 0):

There is no work around except using [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "country",
            localField: "country",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "countries"
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "state",
            localField: "state",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "states"
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "city",
            localField: "city",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "cities"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
                path: "$countries",
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
            }
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
                path: "$states",
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
            }
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
                path: "$cities",
                preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
            }
    }
])
```

Comment: With this approach each document of collection will have to go for processing 3 times, hence with large number of records high time consumption, can there be some other optimized approach as in some kind of nested lookup technique?

Comment: The actual best approach will be to merge the collections as Mongo doesn't like to lookup. i'm not sure if nested lookups will help but i doubt it. feel free to let me know if you try.